Remove width and height attribute in CMS slider wordpress
I am using the cms slider from theme widget in elementor, problem is i have uploaded high resolutions image 1920X1080 for slide but theme slider is resize the image into medium size.
inspect source
need to remove the width & height attribute in cms-slider img tag element only, any solutions on hook or php code to achieve this in function.php?
